# Wi-Fi speed issue with 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, 14.04, realtek, download-speed

I have a strange issue with the Wi-fi speed in Ubuntu 14.04. After a restart of the computer my wlan speeds range at 20-30 Mbs, but after a while of usage (and/or idle) the speed drops to about 2-3 Mbs. After disabling and re-enabling Wi-Fi, the speed is back in the 20-30 Mbs range. I am measuring the speed with http://www.bredbandskollen.se/ which is known to give reliable assessments of network speeds.

I have tried some of the tips here: http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ but it makes no difference. My wireless adapter is ASUS PCE-N15 WLESS PCI-E 802.11N 300MBPS. I get the following output when I run ifconfig, lspci and iwlist power.

Any ideas?

```
...~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:22:0b:91:9d:d0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.197  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ae22:bff:fe91:9dd0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:218256 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200633 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:149638799 (149.6 MB)  TX bytes:88264551 (88.2 MB)

...~$ lspci
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0b)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

...~$ iwlist power
eth0      no power management information.

lo        no power management information.

wlan0     Current mode:off
```

Comment: A simple switch to toggle wifi on/off, i e issuing the command
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down followed by sudo ifconfig wlan0 up would be a nice workaround until the problem is permanently solved. Or maybe this could be done as a script triggered with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Could be [bug #1268833](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1268833)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the same problem. Problem for me is that wifi speed drops about 10x, but it stays connected all the time.

Comment: It is exactly the same wireless chipset as the one you have, so it probably is the same issue. One of the people in that bug report has confirmed that the signal strength appears to be dropping for periods of time for no reason - this will increase the error rate, which in some systems will result in disconnect, in others the speed will drop. What exactly happens when signal strength drops will depend on antenna, distance to AP, and chipset of AP.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

I downloaded the latest drivers for RTL8192CE directly from Realtek [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=278&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2292) and installed by using the script mentioned under section III in the readme file:

```
./compat/script/compat-install.sh
```

and rebooted. Download speed has stayed in the 20-30 MBps range ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Disable IPv6 and Comment out "dns=dnsmasq" within /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

This might fix the problem for some Wi-Fi's, including Yours

Comment: I tried this, but problem persists.

Comment: Sorry about it. I Just saw it once on the internet..

Comment: And it fixed similar Problem for Many, Also, as far as i know your Wi-Fi has the worst compitabiliy among others, from what i've seen..